# netcdf library on MacOS downloaded with Homebrew cannot be linked

Tags: c++, netcdf

I installed netcdf and netcdf-cxx libraries with Homebrew on my MacOS, and for a test, I tried to compile an example code found in the official website https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/examples/programs/SfcPresTempWr.cpp.

From [Linking and using netCDF with gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17775773/linking-and-using-netcdf-with-gcc), I added 2 linker options `-lnetcdf_c++ -lnetcdf` in the compilation command:

```
g++ SfcPresTempWr.cpp -o SfcPresTempWr -lnetcdf_c++ -lnetcdf
```

But the linker produces an error

> ld: library not found for -lnetcdf_c++

I installed netcdf-cxx with `brew install netcdf-cxx`, but there is no netcdf_c++ or netcdf-cxx library in `/usr/local/lib` or `/usr/lib` .
Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: `/usr/local/include` would contain headers, not libs. Try with `/usr/local/lib` or `/usr/lib`. Or search in your root for `netcdf_c++.so` or the same folder as where `netcdf.so` is

Comment: @Ripi2 Thank you for pointing it out, I didn't know the difference between header files and libraries. I modified my question. And thanks to your comment I found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could make it work with the following steps:

Search for the library location with `find /usr -name netcdf-cxx`.
In my case, the location was `/usr/local/Cellar/netcdf-cxx/4.3.1_1/lib/`.

Add the library location to the compilation command with `-L` option and the library name with `-l` option. In my case, the command became:

`g++ SfcPresTempWr.cpp -o SfcPresTempWr -L/usr/local/Cellar/netcdf-cxx/4.3.1_1/lib/ -lnetcdf-cxx4.1.1.0`

It turned out that I didn't need to add `-lnetcdf` at the end of the command, and without `-L` option it compiled successfully as well.